# Logicalness/logicity/logicality

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, differences, terminology, derivational-morphology

The nouns *[logicalness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logicalness)*, *[logicity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logicity)* and *[logicality](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logicality)* are all related to the noun *logic*.

- Is there a grammatical term that describes these "-ness", "-ity" ... words?
- Are these actual English words one can use? Wiktionary has pages for them, but I've never heard them used. Are there differences? Did I miss any others?

As mentioned in the comments, the meaning I'm after is "the degree to which something pertains to logic". The same questions can be posed of derivatives of "chronology": for example, if I have a sequence of events and I reorder them so as to make them chronological, did I enforce the *chronologicalness*, *chronologicity*, or *chronologicality* of the sequence?

Comment: The derivational suffixes _-ness, -ity,_ and _-ality_ get attached to roots and stems to form abstract nouns. _Logic_ is itself an abstract noun, and it's not clear what the words you cite might mean, nor why anybody would use them.  It turns out that derivational morphemes like these can only go on some, not all, stems and roots, and each suffix has its own list. So basically none of these words exist in the sense of being used by English speakers with a meaning, any more than   *_sisterness,_ *_boxity,_ or *_eatology_ do. It's not a random thing.

Comment: The full (subscription-only) OED doesn't list ***logicity***, but it has separate entries for ***logicalness*** (one citation, 1727) and ***logicality*** (three citations, most recent 1873) - both with *exactly* the same definition *(**The quality of being logical**)*. But I agree with John that they're all unnecessary, and probably best avoided.

Comment: *Logicity* doesn't seem to exist, but the ones that turn the adjective *logical* into nouns are recognized in dictionaries.

Comment: @jsw29: Presumably OP seeks a ***noun***, not an adjectival usage such as ***logically valid*** (which probably doesn't mean anything different to ***logical***). Whatever - the base noun ***logic*** would probably work wherever OP might want to use any of his suggestions.

Comment: Adding on to what @JackO'Flaherty says, I'll note that searching Google Books yields many modern uses for both "logicality" and "logicalness".

Comment: The question makes a false assertion. *Logicality* and *logicalness* are not derived from *logic* but from *logical*.

Comment: @jsw29: As it happens, I could only find the morphologically inflected version used in contexts like [*Aristotle also used **logical** terminology in writing on ethical issues*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22used+logical+terminology%22), where I personally would probably have preferred to use the uninflected base noun ***logic*** as a "noun adjunct". For from *removing* ambiguity, using the inflected version there actually *introduces* potential confusion....

Comment: ... specifically, was Aristotle's *actual use* of the terminology logical, or was he (perhaps even *illogically*) simply making use of words commonly associated with the *domain* of "Logic"? There's no such ambiguity with *Aristotle also used **logic** terminology in writing on ethical issues,*

Comment: @tchrist I think 'derived from' is a transitive relation.

Comment: @JohnLawler that's because [the correct term is 'boxicity'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxicity). Whoever made that one up thought it sounded better than 'boxity'.

Comment: As others and I like to say here, not all legitmate (whatever that means) words are in dictionaries. These suffixes are productive (whatever that means) to make understandable and acceptable words (whatever that means) that have never been uttered before. But some affixes sound better with some roots and others with others, there are some guidelines but you know (whatever that means (whatever that means)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Logicalness*, *logicity*, and *logicality* are abstract nouns formed by applying a suffix to the noun *logic* or the adjective *logical*. (The process of adding this suffix is *suffixation*. That word will be relevant in a moment.)

You can use these words, but they're rare and the main difference is relative rarity. Both *[logicalness](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109796)* and *[logicality](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109793)* are in the Oxford English Dictionary. Both definitions are the same:

> the quality of being logical

These are rare words (frequency band 2 and 3 out of 8, respectively). An [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=logicalness%2Clogicality%2Clogicity%2Csuffixation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clogicalness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clogicality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clogicity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuffixation%3B%2Cc0) illustrates the rarity as compared with a similar jargony word from linguistics, *suffixation*:

[image]

Combing through the most recent results, all three appear to be primarily academic in the corpus. These aren't terms showing up in many popular novels:

- *logicalness* is a technical, academic word appearing most often in scholarly monographs or journals ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22logicalness%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1996,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en))
- *logicity* is even rarer, also technical/academic, and usually associated with the work of thinkers like Theodor Adorno or Jacques Derrida ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22logicity%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2013,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en))
- *logicality* is also a technical, academic word, though it seems to appear in broader academic contexts, including literary criticism ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22logicality%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2010,cd_max:2019,lr:lang_1en&tbm=nws&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN2quEh_T5AhWamWoFHQACD144PBD8BSgDegQIARAF&biw=1920&bih=955&dpr=1))

I switched up my approach to see if there were any differences in use outside of academia. Comparing between specific examples searching for news sites (via the [English Corpora NOW corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/)) gives only one accessible result for *logicalness*, in the context of critical pedagogy:

> For instance, the intellectual standards include fairness, depth, accuracy, clarity and **logicalness**. (Ben Harley and Mays Imad, "[5 Essential Ways of Knowing](https://www.insidehighered.com/advice/2022/08/10/importance-thinking-beyond-critical-thinking-opinion)." Inside Higher Ed, 10 August 2022.)

*Logicity* has 4 results, but all referred to a proper noun and not the usage you're asking for.

*Logicality* has 54 results across a wider range of publications, including this example of non-academic usage from MarketWatch:

> Prince Philip applied a military (or perhaps naval) **logicality** to all he did. (Hugo Vickers. "[Prince Philip - active patron of business organizations and consort to Queen Elizabeth II: Obituary."](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/prince-philip-active-patron-of-business-organizations-and-consort-to-queen-elizabeth-ii-has-died-aged-99-11617967051?mod=jennifer-openshaw) MarketWatch, 9 April 2021)

Just in terms of general intelligibility, if you wanted to use these words, *logicality* is the most popular and likely the most recognizable outside an academic context. It's still a fancy, rare word.